# Reporting Services Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: ssrs

I am trying to setup reporting services on a SQL server 2008 and get this error message when I try to connect to the http://localhost/reports

The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

- I asked the server administrator and the IIS should be running (can't find it under administrative tools though)
- I used the Reporting Services Configuration manager to setup reporting services and am pretty sure it is setup correct.

Answer (score 2):

In Report Services 2008 by default it uses its own built-in server, not IIS. You'll need to check in the reporting services directory on your server (its in the usual MSSQL directory in Program Files) to see the configuration files and make changes (you can also make some through reporting services configuration manager). Microsoft does not recommend installing IIS on the reporting services server.

Comment: The SSRS log files will be in in this location too.

Comment: Can you be more explicit regarding the `"usual MSSQL directory in Program Files"`?

Comment: more explicit regarding the _`"usual MSSQL directory in Program Files"`_?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 401 which is a HTTP error code means Unauthorized request. So your IIS is actually running :)

Here is moar to troubleshoot IIS and 401 but it would be really nice to check the logs.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273

Comment: It sounds like you have the authentication methods set in IIS.  Try testing it with a different browser and see if you get a log-in prompt.

Comment: SSRS 2008 doesn't use IIS